# Where do I store Excel Template resources for a Grails Application

Tags: tomcat, grails, resources

I'm trying to access an Excel Template by a string URL from a controller.

1. What directory should I place my Excel Templates in my Grails project?  (i.e., WEB-INF, grails-app/assets, etc.,)
2. What will the URI be for it after packaging it as a .war and putting it in the Tomcat 7 container??

**Edit**

I'm using

```
def wb = new WebXlsxExporter("/path/to/excel/template")
```

Which requires the string URL of where the file is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the answer... ExcelTemplates folder is in the web-app folder.  To get the URL without receiving a file not found error I used

```
request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(.....)
---------
//Which looks like this when implemented

def wb = new WebXlsxExporter(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/ExcelTemplates/testTemplate.xlsx"))
```

When compiled into a war and placed in the Tomcat 7 /webapp directory, everything works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can put them under the web-app directory.  Then you can get them using the following code as an InputStream.

```
private byte[] getLogoBytes() {
    InputStream logo = servletContext.getResourceAsStream('/images/logo.png')
    return logo.getBytes()
}
```